# Daily review within 30days period in mySQL

Tags: mysql

I would like to get a daily review of a turnover summary.

This is the mySQL-Query:

```
SELECT 
 o.date_purchased,
 round(ot.value,2)
FROM orders o
JOIN orders_total ot ON ot.orders_id = o.orders_id
WHERE o.date_purchased <=  '2012-05-12'
AND o.date_purchased >=  '2012-04-12'
AND ot.class =  'ot_total'
```

As the result I get 10 orders with the purchased date.
But I would also get the days within the period where no turnover is, like this example:
2012-04-12   0,00
2012-04-13   120,95
2012-04-14   0,00

Greetz
Ron

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
$todayDate = date("Y-m-d");
$today = strtotime($todayDate);
$nextmonth =  mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")+1, date("d"), date("Y"));
```

and then use this varibles in your query

```
SELECT 
 o.date_purchased,
 round(ot.value,2)
 FROM orders o
 JOIN orders_total ot ON ot.orders_id = o.orders_id
 WHERE o.date_purchased <=  $today
 AND o.date_purchased >=  $nextmonth
 AND ot.class =  'ot_total'
```

You can also use the between

```
SELECT 
 o.date_purchased,
 round(ot.value,2)
 FROM orders o
 JOIN orders_total ot ON ot.orders_id = o.orders_id
 WHERE ot.class =  'ot_total'
 AND o.date_purchased  BETWEEN $today AND $nextmonth
```

Comment: But then I also get only the purchase date with the belonging orders. The purchased dates without an order are still missing.

Comment: i think you need to crate a view that contains all dates with no gaps

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do what you want just by changing the query as SQL will not add rows when they simply do not exist.

Two possible solutions:

- Fill the gaps in the application when displaying the results - the recommended solution.
- Create an additional table that contains all dates with no gaps and make an outer join with `orders` table first, although it is generally pointless to do it this way.